# Removing item from usestate using filter

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-state

This question has been asked a lot but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have two object, one contains a list of all user and one contains a list of invited user, I want to remove from list1 the elements from list2.

```js
    const [query, setQuery] = React.useState('')
    const [inv, setInv] = React.useState([])
    const [results, setResults] = React.useState([])  
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            let {data} = await http.commercial.getMedecinsByEmail({'email': query});

            for (var key in inv) {
                for (var key2 in data) {
                    if (inv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
                            if (inv[key] === data[key2].id) {
                                console.log("medecin : " + data[key2].id + " already invited");
                                data = data.filter(function(){
                                    return true;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            setResults(data);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [query]);
```

I don't understand why `data` still contains the entries that are contained in `inv`

Comment: your logic have flaws. first loop won't iterate because initially inv has no value. data.filter does nothing to filter want you want. Put condition in it. Tip: don't reuse variable data and practice inverted if to lessen nested if/else condition. Not sure what data is but if it is an object, use object.keys if want to get the first level properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I didn't understand right at the first time, I should do my two loops because filter already solves the issue.

```js
            data = data.filter(item => !inv.includes(item.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter `data = data.filter(() => true);` will return array with same elements. You need to add some condition like `data = data.filter((item) => item == "a");` in order to keep elements which satisfy condition.

Answer (score -1):

man, so my suggestion is to use some kind of off-the-shelf solution. For example you can use `lodash`, so lodash includes `romove` function

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove